# How do I submit a real-time validated form with Semantic UI and Meteor?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, meteor, semantic-ui

I have run into a huge problem with my form, which I validate in real time using Semantic UI.

The HTML:

```
<form class="ui form pin-form">                     
  <div class="field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input placeholder="name@example.com" name="email_input" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="ui buttons">
    <input type="submit" class="ui submit positive disabled button login-button" value="Log in">
  </div>
</form>
```

I added the `<form>` tag myself and made the submit into an `input` so that I could access the regular `submit form`.

The real time validation comes from Semantic UI and a Meteor package: https://github.com/avrora/live-form-validator

On template render I do this:

```
if (!this._rendered) {
this._rendered = true;
pinForm = $('.ui.form.pin-form');
pinForm.form({
    my_text_input: {
      identifier: 'email_input',
      rules: [
        {
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Type your email address'
        },
        {
          type: 'email',
          prompt: 'This is not yet a valid email address'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    inline: true,
    on: 'blur',
    transition: 'slide down',
    onSuccess: function () {
      var submitButton = $('.ui.submit.button')
                submitButton.removeClass('disabled')
                return false
    },
            onFailure: function() {
                var submitButton = $('.ui.submit.button')
                submitButton.addClass('disabled')
            }
    })
}
```

The big problem here is that with `return false` it doesn't submit the form at all even when click the submit button, and without it it submits the form in real time, which I don't want!

Can anyone see a workaround or do I need to switch validation somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the stupidest question on all of SO. (Don't worry, I asked the question so I'm only dissing myself!)

Semantic UI literally provides the `on: change` setting, which will validate the form in real time instead of `on: blur` which it is set to now.

Oh, man...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a `Meteor.call`, you could try doing it in the `onSuccess` function. The package does ask you to save the data manually within the `onSuccess` function.

The following code logged the email twice.

```
onSuccess: function () {
    console.log("Email: ", $("input[name=email_input]").val());
    // Submit your form here using a Meteor.call maybe?
    return false;
},
```

You could alternatively look at [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) for handling forms in Meteor.

Comment: The meteorpad doesn't work at all for me, the buttons remains grey. The problem is that I don't want to submit the form in real time, only by manually submitting the form!

Comment: Try hitting 'enter' after filling out the email, it worked for me. I do not understand what you mean by "submit the form in real time". When you put in your form submission logic within "onSuccess", you are submitting it only when the form validates. If you want to check for something else, you could add that logic there

Comment: Exactly, but it validates in real time! After each keypress, in fact.

Comment: The package documentation seems pretty limited too. No issues, no updates.. You should totally check out autoform.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it was the only package I could find that provided real time validation. Autoform doesn't. :(

Comment: You could try adding another non submit button, hide/show it appropriately by using the onSuccess, onFailure and that button click listener could do your submission logic?